# How to save/load a 2d array containing unicode to/from a .txt file [Python] [encoding issues][utf8]

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

So the basic issue i am having is when i write to the txt file the unicode character *\u2656* becomes this *b'\xe2\x99\x96'* (i believe this is byte code?). Then when i read the file i cannot decode it back to *\u2656*.

Board_visual is just a 2d array where each item is either a unicode character or None type (an empty square). It is used to represent the position of pieces on a chess board used by my tkinter gui. The actual pieces are objects so this is just the unicode characters that represent chess pieces.

Example board_visual contents

```
['♖', '♘', '♗', '♔', '♕', '♗', '♘', '♖']
['♙', None, '♙', '♙', '♙', '♙', '♙', '♙']
[None, '♙', None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, '♟', None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
['♟', '♟', '♟', None, '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟']
['♜', '♞', '♝', '♚', '♛', '♝', '♞', '♜']
```

Here is the code i used:

```
def save():
    filename=input("Enter the name of the file")
    myFile=open(str(filename)+".txt","w")
    for i in board_visual:
        for j in i:
            myFile.write(str(str(j).encode('utf8')))
            myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()
```

It gives this file format (in the .txt file):

```
b'\xe2\x99\x97'
b'\xe2\x99\x98'
b'\xe2\x99\x96'
b'None'
b'\xe2\x99\x99'
b'\xe2\x99\x99'
b'None'
b'\xe2\x99\x99'
b'\xe2\x99\x99'
b'\xe2\x99\x99'
b'\xe2\x99\x99'
b'None'
...
```

Then i attempt to read it with

```
def load():
    global board_visual
    global board
    filename=input("Enter the name of the file")
    myFile=open(str(filename)+".txt","r", encoding='utf8')
    index=0
    index2=0
    for i in myFile:
        if i!="b'None'\n":
            i=i.strip("\n")
            board_visual[index//8][index%8]=i#places it into the 8*8 grid
        else:
            board_visual[index//8][index%8]=None
        index=index+1
    myFile.close()
```

A few posts on this website mention using .decode but that only works in python 2 i'm using python 3.3, This program worked perfectly when i didn't have any unicode characters.This means the issue must be with the encoding but this is my first time working with it and i can't seem decode it correctly. I have looked through the many similar questions on the website but none of the solutions worked for me (many were for Python 2)
I have originally tried without the .encode(utf8) when writing to the file but that gave me the error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2656' in position 0: character maps to  from researching the error i added the .encode(utf8) but this causes the issues when decoding it back to unicode in the program.  I also used unicode(i) but this was an unknown command.

As there are only 12 different characters i could create a if/elif statement that checks them and converts them my self but this is clearly a very poor solution.

I'm rather new to programming and python is my only language, this is used in a chess game engine. (my first large project)
I'm not sure what i'm missing. Any help would be appreciated and i hope my post meets the requirements. If there is a website you can recommend to help me learn about python encoding then that would be great too, i just can't seem to get this working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't byte code, those are encoded bytes. It's because you did `myFile.write(str(str(j).encode('utf8')))` The fundamental problem you are having is you are simply dumping the string representation of your data to a file and calling it serialization. Instead, use one of the ready-made serialization formats. `json` is text-based, `pickle` is binary. You can probably just use `json`, what is actually in `board_visual`?

Comment: But you probably were just looking for `myFile.write(j)`, but you are better off using `json`

Comment: Edited post to explain what board_visual is. Also myFile.write(j) gives me the encoding error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2656' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>" as above. you mention json i'm afraid i know nothing about it (still very new to programming) is this something i can research to fix my issue? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. tested on python 3.6

```
chess = "♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ \u2655 \u2656 \u2657 \u2658 \u2659 \u265a"
f = open('file', 'wb')
f.write(chess.encode('utf8'))
f.close()

f = open('file', 'rb')
print (f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: why not simply `f.write(chess)` and leave out `'wb'` and provide `'w'` with `encoding='utf8')?

Comment: ^ Would work i believe but it gives me the error "TypeError: must be str, not None" i assume because None is not text

Comment: @ANewling you can't write `None`. you can write an empty string or `"None"`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga do you mean `open('file', 'w').write(chess)`?

Comment: Fixed used a basic if statement to replace none type with 'None' (text rather than None type) then when loading it i do the reverse. Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly not what you really want to do, but `ast.literal_eval` is able to reverse your serialization of utf8 encoded data:

```
>>> t = r"b'\xe2\x99\x96'"
>>> print(t)
b'\xe2\x99\x96'
>>> print(ast.literal_eval(r"b'\xe2\x99\x96'").decode())
♖
>>> print(hex(ord(ast.literal_eval(r"b'\xe2\x99\x96'").decode())))
0x2656
```

But that is really ugly and you should either use json or directly rely on the ability of Python to automatically encode and decode unicode in utf-8:

```
    for j in i:
        myFile.write(j)
        myFile.write("\n")
```

as suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga in his comment

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem in your code is this part:

```
str(str(j).encode('utf8'))
```

In general, your code is littered with calls to `str`. Most of them are unnecessary and confusing, but harmless. But this one is harmful.

It may help to try each part of the expression out on the interactive interpreter. If `j` is a string, then `str(j)` is a copy of that same string. And then `str(j).encode(‘utf8’)` is a `bytes` holding the UTF-8 encoding of that string. And then `str(str(j).encode(‘utf8’))` is the string representations of that bytes object, which is going to be a letter b and some quotes with a bunch of backslash escapes in between. So that’s what you end up writing to the file.

If you just use `j.encode(‘utf8’)`, this problem will go away, but it’s probably just the first of many problems. Most likely, the next one is the fact that you’re opening a text-mode file, but then trying to write encoded `bytes` to it instead of strings. Which you’ll fix by just not doing the encode and just using `j`. And so on.

More generally, you need to understand what you’re doing before you have any hope of Python knowing what you’re trying to do. If you don’t know why you’re calling `str` somewhere, why would you call it?

In Python (3.0 and later), you shouldn’t be dealing with encodings all over the place. Just specify the encoding once, as close to the edge as possible. In particular, if you want to write some Unicode to a UTF-8 file, just write Unicode to a UTF-8 file:

```
s = ‘\u1234\u2345’
with open(‘myfile.txt’, ‘w’, encoding=‘utf-8’) as f:
    f.write(s)
```

That’s it. No calls to `encode` or `decode` or `str` needed, and no dealing with `bytes` objects anywhere.